# Time delta gives 0.0 output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get time delta to run a linear search. When I run on debug mode, the delta variable is logging the difference but when ran as regular python script, print isn't giving the right result. It prints 0.0 even if I change the target which isn't accurate time difference.

```
import time
import itertools

def linear_search(arry, target):
    for index, value in enumerate(arry):
        if value == target:
            return True
        return False

k = list(itertools.islice(range(2000000), 1, 2000000, 2))
start = time.time()
linear_search(k, 25)
done = time.time()
delta = done - start 
print(delta)
```

Can someone help to find if there's anything wrong in the print statement?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: It prints `0.0009868144989013672` for me. Which makes sense, it's a linear search that searches for 25 in an array with numbers in increasing order.

Comment: `time.time()` does not necessarily have great resolution. You might try timing it with `timeit.timeit()` or maybe check out `time.time_ns()`

Comment: Hence my question about OS. The code in the question has a syntax error, but on Linux, I find that it consistently reports a non-zero difference between two separate `time.time()` return values, even if there is no intervening code (differences of order microseconds). I'm prepared to believe that on some other OS, that might not be the case.

Comment: @JonSG Actually, its `time.perfcounter` or something like that.

Comment: Okay, I see that the syntax error in the question has now been corrected. But unless info re OS is provided soon, I am going to vote to close this question as non-reproducible. It is consistently reporting time differences of order 15 microseconds on my system - never zero.

Comment: @alani It isn't, and that's why this question.

Comment: @alani On my system in both Windows and linux the original code reports a time delta of 0. The function is too fast for the resolution of `time.time()` to measure. One can measure it with `timeit` though.

Comment: I'm running it in VS Code on windows PC with bash terminal. I could see if I increases the target to a higher number like linear_Search(k, 1000000) it prints the time.

Comment: @Gladiator Thanks for the OS information - although best to put it in the question itself.

Comment: @JonSG Thanks, that solves the issue. Even if the target number is significantly small or near the starting index of sorted array , the milli/nano second is properly shown with `timeit.timeit()`

Comment: @Gladiator If JonSG's answer has solved it for you, then you could consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: @alani Yes, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be the resolution of `time.time()` particularly on Windows. I believe the resolution there is apparently 16 milliseconds.

There is a different package (`timeit`) that is more oriented to timing very short method calls.

Here is an example:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
def linear_search(arry, target):
    for index, value in enumerate(arry):
        if value == target:
            return True
        return False

k = list(itertools.islice(range(2000000), 1, 2000000, 2))
n = 25
'''

print(timeit.timeit("linear_search(k, n)", setup=setup, number=1000))
```

This gives me an average of `0.00021399999999999197` over 1000 runs